# multiple files upload with progress bar using Amazon in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am using Amazon library to upload single file to server. I am using [this code to upload single image](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-simpl3r), but now i want to upload and pass multiple files in `UploadService` service.

I checked inside UploadService class and inside this service class, they are using following code to start upload.

```
uploader = new Uploader(this, s3Client, s3BucketName, s3ObjectKey, fileToUpload);
```

Here fileToUpload = file path of single image.

Did anybody use this same service and uploaded multiple files? Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent couple of days on this and finally got something interesting. Here is amazon s3 lib which provide multiple upload with resume and cancle functionality.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: This is what i am looking for. Thanks mate ;-)

Comment: @Hardik, can you please let me know which part of the s3 lib helped you to get the multiple file upload ?

Comment: Already seen and implement the file upload code snippet from the given sample.The given code only upload one file at a time.How to handle the list of files upload using the given sample code? Can you please explain how to achieve with same sample code